24.04: connecting to a public wifi with a captive portal takes a long time
Seemingly any time I connect to a public, unencrypted wifi network (e.g. in a train), the time it takes between choosing the network and actually getting connected exceeds several minutes.
Usually, when this is the case, I can also not abort the connection in any way: whether I try to switch to an encrypted network (e.g. my phone hotspot) or restart NetworkManager, or even try to reboot: nothing will work until this time as elapsed.
Hardware: Thinkpad T14s (5th Gen Intel), Network controller: Intel Corporation Meteor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 20). Ubuntu 24.04 on 6.10 kernel (it also happened on the 6.8 kernel).
A potentially important detail is that these Wifi networks all have captive portals, so perhaps NetworkManager is attempting to connect to verify if the internet is available, and it needs to time out before it actually allows me to use the connection?
